# Settings Page- Settings Combination Results

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have a settings page for an app I am creating to generate passwords. In my option page there are 5 options the user can select.

I am wondering how I can make my code much simpler than having an `if` for each possible outcome. I started out having 3 options which made it easy, but now there are so many combinations the code is becoming messy and I'm not sure how to go about writing this better.

The code below is for three options the user can select:

Main Activity Java

```
  btnGenPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked ==  1 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 1 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 1) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&*()".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 1 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 1) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 1) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 0) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }
                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 1 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 0) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!£$%^&*()".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 1 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 1) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!£$%^&*()".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);

            }else if (SettingsPage.isSpecChecked == 0 && SettingsPage.isHighCaseChecked == 1 && SettingsPage.isNumbChecked == 0) {
                char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < SettingsPage.passLength; i++) {
                    char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
                    sb.append(c);
                }

                final String output = sb.toString();
                passView.setText(output);
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see there are a number of statements with all possible combinations, but now I have added more settings there are lots of combinations with possible results.
I believe there are 32 possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of repeating code. The only thing that actually changes is the character set from which you generate the password. The first thing you should do is move the repeating code to a method.

```
private void generatePassword(char[] charset) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
        char c = charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }

    final String output = sb.toString();
    passView.setText(output);
}
```

The next part is to handle the character set generation. For this you can create variables that store the charset for each option like numbers, special characters, upper case, lower case and so on. Then based of the options that are turned on/off to generate the final character set.

```
private char[] generateCharSet() {
    String numbers = "0123456789";
    String special = "!£$%^&*()";
    String alphabetsLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String alphabetsUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // Add lower alphabets by default
    StringBuilder finalCharset = new StringBuilder(alphabetsLower);

    // Add special chars if option is selected
    if (isSpecChecked == 1) {
        finalCharset.append(special);
    }

    // Add upper case chars if option is selected
    if (isHighCaseChecked == 1) {
        finalCharset.append(alphabetsUpper);
    }

    // Add numbers if option is selected
    if (isNumbChecked == 1) {
        finalCharset.append(numbers);
    }

    // build the final character set
    return finalCharset.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

Call these methods inside the `onClick` method. Hope you get the idea.

Here is the whole java class I mocked with a unit to test the functions. It was written in Netbeans IDE. Good luck :)

**PasswordGeneratorClass.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author K Neeraj Lal
 */
public class PasswordGeneratorClass {

    private static final int passLength = 40;

    private static int isSpecChecked;
    private static int isHighCaseChecked;
    private static int isNumbChecked;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Iterates from 000 to 111
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            unitTest(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used for testing only
     *
     * @param test input
     */
    private static void unitTest(int test) {
        char[] arr = Integer.toBinaryString(test).toCharArray();

        // turn on/off the options based
        isSpecChecked = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : '0'));
        isHighCaseChecked = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : '0'));
        isNumbChecked = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(arr.length > 2 ? arr[2] : '0'));

        char[] charset = generateCharSet();
        generatePassword(charset);
    }

    /**
     * Generates character set
     *
     * @return character set
     */
    private static char[] generateCharSet() {
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String special = "!£$%^&*()";
        String alphabetsLower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String alphabetsUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        // Add lower alphabets by default
        StringBuilder finalCharset = new StringBuilder(alphabetsLower);

        // Add special chars if option is selected
        if (isSpecChecked == 1) {
            finalCharset.append(special);
        }

        // Add upper case chars if option is selected
        if (isHighCaseChecked == 1) {
            finalCharset.append(alphabetsUpper);
        }

        // Add numbers if option is selected
        if (isNumbChecked == 1) {
            finalCharset.append(numbers);
        }

        // build the final character set
        return finalCharset.toString().toCharArray();
    }

    /**
     * Generates the password based on character set
     *
     * @param charset the character set to generate the password from
     */
    private static void generatePassword(char[] charset) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < passLength; i++) {
            char c = charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }

        final String output = sb.toString();
        // passView.setText(output);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```